# Возвращаемое значение метода

Tags: ооп

При возвращении объекта из метода его тип должен быть максимально определен или наоборот?

P.S. Сей вопрос у меня созрел при чтении книги "Совершенный код" С. Макконнелла. Вот цитата:
"При возвращении объекта из метода обычно следует возвращать максимально определенный тип объекта."
Что у меня вызывало сомнения и я решил спросить у гуру)

Comment: Это вопрос вообще или в применении к определенному языку?

Comment: Наоборот :D

Comment: Наоборот =)))

Comment: @Ігар Цімошка, Если Вы добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Comment: т.е. вы сомневаетесь в компетенции Макконнелла?

Answer (score 1):

> "Абстракция выделяет существенные
> характеристики некоторого объекта,
> отличающие его от всех других видов
> объектов и, таким образом, четко
> определяет его концептуальные границы
> с точки зрения наблюдателя.
>
> Абстрагирование концентрирует внимание
> на внешних особенностях объекта и
> позволяет отделить самые существенные
> особенности поведения от
> несущественных."

*из книги "Объектно-ориентированный анализ и проектирование" Гради Буч*

Возвращайте объект максимально определённый для данной конкретной задачи. Если Вы этого не сделаете, то в некоторых случаях придётся использовать приведение типов, что с точки зрения ООП не есть хорошо.

Всю остальную часть информации об объекте нужно скрыть. Чем меньше будет известно информации об объекте, тем легче этой информацией будет управлять.

Answer (score 0):

Если язык строго-типизированный, то, наверно, должен быть максимально определен. Если нет - смотри по обстоятельствам, что ты возвращаешь: если ты возвращаешь именно объект с данными (в понимании `JS`, например), то это `ValueObject` и пусть он будет просто набором пар ключ-значение. А если ты возвращаешь экземпляр класса (из фабрики, например), то, конечно, стоит ему иметь тип.

Кстати, вот я ответ накатал и задумался - а как это, "максимально определен"?

Comment: >а как это, "максимально определен"?

на примере C# интерфейс `IEnumerable<T>` это "минимально определённый" тип, а класс `List<T>`, который реализует этот и некоторые другие интерфейсы - это "максимально определённый" тип

Comment: Чуть-чуть стало яснее, но всеж... Тот же C# умеет вернуть экземпляр класса и только, если я не ошибаюсь - все является экземплярами. Тогда мы в любом случае вернем экземпляр класса, который либо реализовал интерфейс, либо не реализовал. Получается, если класс не реализовал - минимально определенный, если реализовал - максимально? Не подумайте, что я придираюсь - действительно хочу разобраться и понять.

Comment: покажу примером:

    public IEnumerable<int> Method()
    {
        //return Enumerable.Range(0,10);
        //return new int[]{1,2,3};
        //return new List<int>{1,2,3};
    }

как видите в случае если метод возвращает интерфейс, вы можете вернуть любой тип, реализующий этот интерфейс, но так делать нежелательно, если нужен будет например доступ по индексу, тогда вам прийдётся производить кастинг. вобщем всё зависит от ситуации

Comment: с другой стороны, тип аргумента должен быть наименее строгим:

     public IEnumerable<int> Method(IEnumerable<int> value) { ... }

опять же, чтобы метод был более гибким:

     Method(Enumerable.Range(0,10));
     Method(new int[]{1,2,3});
     Method(new List<int>{1,2,3});

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Все параметры аргументов и возвращаемый тип должны быть максимально абстрагированы, только без потери функционала.

Пример кода с комментариями:

```
// абстракное рисуемое "тело"
interface IDrawable {
    void paint();
}

// точка 
class Point implements IDrawable {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public void moveTo(Point p) {
        this.x = p.x;
        this.y = p.y;
    }

    public Point getClone() {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.moveTo(this);

        return point;
    }

    // будем рисовать точку стандартного цвета
    @Override
    public void paint() {
        // предположим что 'из за нюансов реализации' 
        // для прорисовки нам надо использовать копию обьекта
        Point cloned = getClone();

        // рисуем точку
    }

}

// та же точка только с цветом
class Pixel extends Point {
    public Color color;

    // нет смысла переопределять данный метод для аргумента типа pixel
    // т.к. класс поинт уже несет всю необходимую в себе информацию
    // для того чтоб переместить обьект
    public void moveTo(Pixel p) {
        super.moveTo(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint() {
        // а вот здесь у нас при использовании метода getClone()
        // возникает ошибка, т.к. мы используем метод который определен в классе поинт
        // но возвращаемый им тип для нас не подходит, мы потеряли информацию о цвете.
        Point cloned = getClone(); // этот метод надо переопределить в классе пиксель

        // рисуем цветную точку
    }

    // А вот если убрать коментарий вокруг данного метода то с методом paint 
    // все будет ОК. getClone будет возвращать нужный нам тип   
    // и переменной 'cloned' можно будет поменять тип на пиксель
    /*
    @Override
    public Pixel getClone() {
        Pixel cloned = new Pixel();
        cloned.moveTo(super.getClone());
        return cloned;
    }
    */
}

// какой-то очень сложный рисуемый обьект
// который состоит из других обьектов помельче
class ComplexDrawing implements IDrawable {
    private List<IDrawable> items = new LinkedList<IDrawable>();

    // можно, но не имеет смысла. ведь для прорисовки обьекта вполне достаточно
    // просто иметь ссылку на интерфейс IDrawable
    public void add(Pixel item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    // можно, но не имеет смысла. ведь для прорисовки обьекта вполне достаточно
    // просто иметь ссылку на интерфейс IDrawable
    public void add(Point item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    // позволяет добавлять любые обьекты типа IDrawable
    public void add(IDrawable item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint() {
        for (IDrawable item : items) {
            item.paint();
        }
    }
}
```